# Delphi - Diagnosing Access Violations on App Closure

Tags: delphi, debugging, access-violation

Delphi XE6 - I am writing a a plugIn for MS Excel using Add-In Express.  I have been working on this for a while, and the project has been stable.  I recently made several changes and am now running into issues.  When I run Excel, my plugIn gets loaded. I load an Excel spreadsheet, and then immediately exit. I now see a debugger notification.

```
Project EXCEL.EXE raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x2a5014ca: read o address 0x00000005'.
```

The changes I made were basically nothing more than moving some global variables into it's own unit, which then let me take out some dependencies (i.e. I was able to remove some of my own files from the UNIT clause.)  I did a complete build, and the compiler did not complain about that, so it is finding the variables OK.

What have I done to try to identify the issue?

1. I have done a BREAK when I get the debugger notification.  Unfortunately, this throws me into CPU view, and all I see is assembler.  I cannot identify from this what portion of my code is being called.
2. I have enabled MadExcept, but I immediately get a stack overflow when starting Excel. I have raised the Stack size from 1 MB to 2 MB, but I still get a stack overflow.
3. I have set AQTime profiler to Allocations and tried 'Run with Profiling'.  When I do this, Delphi hangs and Windows restarts it.  I get the same behavior with the other AQTime profilers as well.
4. I have tried commenting out my startup code, on Initialization and on Finalization routines.

One other point to mention, I set a breakpoint in BOTH my Initilization code as well as finalization code.  (I mean the keyword in the .pas file, not a generic starting and closing down section).  The debugger stop on the Initilization routine.  WHen I close out of Excel, I would expect the debugger to stop on the Finalization code, but it does NOT.  I don't know if this means that the error occurs prior to this point (but there shouldn't be any code running between telling Excel to close and when Finalization is called) or does it mean that the debugger just can't capture that point...?

Other than going back to a previous version of my code, what else can I be checking?  How can I see what is generating my error?

Here is the call stack I am seeing.
[image]

Comment: In your 1 scenario, do you see a call stack in the IDE? If so, what is it? Also, the read offset of 0x00000005 from the error message might offer a clue. Do you have a heap allocated type with a field at that offset? It might be a pointer to one of those, which is prematurely set to nil. Object fields are typically dword aligned, and this one is not.

Comment: I added a call stack screenshot above.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd persevere with madexcept. I use it in this scenario, an add-in express excel com add-in. You need to get that working really. Don't mess with the stack size. That won't help. Stack overflow likely unterminated recursion. Simple solution will be to use revision control to isolate the smallest possible change that introduces fault.

Comment: @@David - I agree with your suggestion, but let me ask a question.  If it is unterminated recursion, shouldn't I see other issues, really sluggish performance, etc.

Comment: *I have enabled MadExcept, but I immediately get a stack overflow when starting Excel.* That's an unterminated recursion. Increasing the stack size just delays the inevitable. Your main problem is something else.

Comment: It's incorrect to assume that no code would run between your telling Excel to close and your DLL's finalization sections getting executed. Excel is going to call your DLL's `xlAutoClose` function, and maybe `xlAutoFree`, too. You could set breakpoints there, or you could try the "run to next source line" debugger command, which should notify you as soon as *any* function from your DLL runs.

Comment: By moving code into a new unit, you probably altered initialisation/finalisation sequences in a subtle and problematic way. (This is where the combination of globals, **initialization** & **finalization** become dangerous.) You may be able make some progress investigating the problem by compiling with Debug Info and stepping through `InitUnits` and `FinalizeUnits` from `System.pas`.